# Fazer logout não está funcionando

Tags: suporte

Preciso fazer logout no site e não me aparece o botão de logout, aqui no SOpt. Uso Opera como browser.

Essa é minha tela
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Mudou só o ícone. Dá uma clicada nos outros que você acha. Agora não tem mais o nome, mas é o memso símbolo de antes, além de estar no fim em vez de no começo como antes.

Comment: Na dúvida sempre é possivel limpar os dados de sessão do seu navegador...

Comment: Não aparece o botão sair, logout e etc

Comment: Clica no último item do topo, o do balãozinho

Comment: Já fiz isso e funcionou, @bfavaretto. Ok, valeu!!